# mootools each not iterating for me

Tags: mootools, each

I'm going nuts here but the each function is just not working for me.
I have about 20 elements with a class name of "lookup" (text boxes) and this function successfully turns all elements red:

```
    document.addEvent('domready', function()
    {
        var tb = $$('.lookup');
        tb.setStyle("color", "red");
    });
```

However, in the following code, I would expect to get some alert for each element but the alert don't hit at all, and no exception is raised either.  It is like the each is iterating through 0 items....

```
    document.addEvent('domready', function()
    {
        var tb = $$('.lookup');
        tb.each(function(el) 
        {
            alert("hi"); 
        });
    });
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?
In both examples above, I used $$('.lookup').each and $$('.lookup').setStyle() with the same outcome (example 1 works; example 2 doesn't).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it works for me, your code pasted into JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/YqTEt/.  Are to getting any errors for the browser debug tools

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, no.  I'm using Google Chrome's Developer Tools window, Console doesn't show up any exceptions.

Comment: Something is odd.  I tried in JSFiddle too and it works, but still not in my own code.  Am including mootools-core-1.4.5-full-nocompat-yc.js for the mootools library.

Answer (score 3):

Which browsers have problems? Try use 'window' instead 'document'

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    var tb = $$('.lookup');
    tb.each(function(el){
        el.setStyle("color", "red");
        alert("hi"); 
    });
});
```

In mootools better always use 'each' for working with array of elements.

Comment: Hi wearwoolf, 

I tried "window.addEvent" but still fails.  

Browsers: it fails in all browsers tested: IE9 and latest versions of Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I think that that problem is now actually as an indirect result of exceptions that occur in ASP.NET's boilerplate Javascript.  For some reason, the likes of $$('.lookup') still run but .each doesn't.  

The exceptions appearing in IE9 and Chrome are "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'enumReservedName' of undefined" [ScriptResource.axd:1652], "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'argumentUndefined' of undefined" [ScriptResource.axd:357] and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'argumentTypeWithTypes' of undefined" [ScriptResource.axd:330].

Comment: OK.  ASP.NET's exception is a result of Sys.Res not being defined.  When I comment out the mootools include (and document.addEvent() code) then ASP.NET does not have an exception.

Surely Mootools and ASP.NET frameworks should work side-by-side?  For some reason, including mootools (1.4.5) is causing Sys.Res to not be defined.

Can't find anything obvious cases of this on the net at the moment.

Comment: There appears to be a conflict between the use of "Type" in both frameworks.  I've tried doing a search/replace in mootools from Type to mooType but getting other errors cropping up then.  This page appears to describe my problem: https://mootools.lighthouseapp.com/projects/2706/tickets/1045-asp-net-bug

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that reordering the mootools include script so that it is referenced **after** the Microsoft `WebResource.axd?d=` include script resolves the problem.  Mootools appears to handle the conflict, whereas Microsoft ASP.NET can't.